# "Multiplying" a line of code

Tags: c#

I'm new to programming and I simply need a section of my code to be repeated multiple times (100 in my case) without having to actually copy and paste it again and again (because that would look rather ugly). Here's the line in question:

```
Console.WriteLine ();
        Console.WriteLine ("Q7: x² - 4x + 4 = 0");
        int ans8 = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
        if (ans8 == 2) {
            ++experiencePoints;
            ++experiencePoints;
            ++experiencePoints;
            ++experiencePoints;
            ++experiencePoints;
            ++experiencePoints;
            ++experiencePoints;
            ++experiencePoints;
            ++experiencePoints;
            ++experiencePoints;
            Console.WriteLine ("Correct");
```

In other words I want the program to recognise '++experiencePoints' 100 times without having to write it out like i just did

Comment: `experiencePoints += 100;`

Comment: Why would you add one to a number 100 times instead of just adding 100 to the number once?

Comment: It didn't occur to you to simply add by a number other than 1??

Comment: *[dinging sound of slot machine winning]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    ++experiencePoints;
```

However, in your specific case, you can just add 100 to `experiencePoints`, like so:

```
experiencePoints += 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    ++experiencePoints;
}
```

Or just use :

```
experiencePoints += 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

`++experiencePoints` adds 1 to `experiencePoints`, but the [`+=`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx) operator will add any amount you specify to the variable.

Try `experiencePoints += 100;`, which is shorthand for `experiencePoints = experiencePoints + 100`

You do not need to add numbers 1 at a time. Note that using a `for` loop like others have suggested, solves your problem, but you should never ever do it that way, as it will take more memory and time.